# CLLocationManager not calling didUpdateLocations

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, cllocationmanager

I've been unable to figure out why location manager isn't providing updates to me. I've added the key, tested on simulator and on a device.

Edit: STDOUT also contains "Delegate: "

**STDOUT**

```
2014-11-28 22:18:30.066 Speedo[14091:150298] Status: 4
2014-11-28 22:18:30.069 Speedo[14091:150298] Is when in use? 1
2014-11-28 22:18:30.158 Speedo[14091:150298] New status: 4
2014-11-28 22:18:30.159 Speedo[14091:150298] Is when in use? 1
```

**FirstViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel* speedLabel;
@end
```

**FirstViewController.cpp**

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface FirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation FirstViewController {
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.speedLabel.text = @"";

    if([locationManager respondsToSelector: @selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
        [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }

    // locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    // locationManager.distanceFilter = 0.01;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    NSLog(@"Delegate: %@", locationManager.delegate);
    NSLog(@"Status: %d", [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]);
    NSLog(@"Is when in use? %d", [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
    UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorAlert show];
}

-(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status {
    NSLog(@"New status: %d", status);
    NSLog(@"Is when in use? %d", [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse);
    [manager startUpdatingLocation];
}

-(void)locationManage: (CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray*)locations {
    CLLocation* last = [locations lastObject];
    NSLog(@"Speed: %f m/s", last.speed); // meter per second
    // TODO: support mutli-units
    // m/s -> mph
    // 1 -> 2.236
    self.speedLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)(last.speed * 2.23694)];
}

@end
```

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm using an adhoc signing on Pangu 8.1 and AngelXWing's app sync.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it's just the result of a typo.

```
-(void)locationManage: (CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray*)locations {
```

should be

```
-(void)locationManager: (CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray*)locations {
```

You forgot the "r" at the end of "locationManager".